# Selenium driver.quit is throwing error where as driver.close works

Tags: java, selenium

Everytime i use `driver.quit()`, I get an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to find executable for: taskkill 
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:250)
```

but when I change the code to `java.close()`, it does shut down the page. Can you please explain why this happens?

Comment: Please provide what browser and browser version you are using as well as what version of Selenium.

Comment: Post ur code please !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna out on limb here and guess you're on Windows platform. Anyway, "Unable to find executable for: taskkill" means that the directory c:\windows\system32 is not present in the [PATH](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) environment variable. So if you add that, you're good to go.